# Get keywords from a string or group of strings

Tags: php

Is there a way to extract keywords from a string?

```
Eg. string = "Obi goes to school"
```

How can keywords like "school" or Obi be extracted from the string.

Platform is php/mysql

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Define "keyword". Why is "Obi" or "school" a keyword? Is "to" also a keyword? What criteria do you want to use to extract them?

Comment: @Pekka +1. @Frank. Why not accept some answers while you're at it?

Comment: @Keyne. Use regex with care. Use strpos where possible. It's often the better way to go performance wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If you're trying to get a specific word

There are many common string methods (reference is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)) that do some variation of this task. The most simple would be `strpos()`, which finds the position of the first occurrence of a string in a larger string.

```
$str = "Obi goes to school";
$school_pos = strpos($str, "school");
```

You can also look into regular expressions if you need to match more complex patterns.

### If you're trying to just get a list of words in general

In this case, `$word_array = explode(' ', $some_str);` works like a charm.

Comment: I think you meant to say `explode`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$strings = explode (' ','Obi goes to school');
```

That will separate them out into an array. If by keywords you meant nouns, then get a dictionary file that shows parts of speech, then loop through the array of strings and determine if each entry is a noun using the dictionary. Which will obviously be quirky, language is a tough thing to program reliably.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already know what the string is going to be and you want to do something with the various tokens that you can extract from the string, you could always try `explode()`.

```
<?php
     $string = "Here are my tokens.";
     $tokens = explode(" ", $string);
?>
```

And so `echo $tokens[0];` would print **Here**, `echo $tokens[2];` would print **my**, etc.

If you just want to find a specific word, use `strpos()`.

```
<?php
     $string = "Here is my string.";
     $keyword = "is";
     $pos = strpos($keyword, $string);
     echo $pos; // This would print 5.
?>
```